# How to change cmake build directory in `cmake-kits.json` or `cmake-variants.json` of vscode

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, cmake

I want to run the cmake and build to different output directories depend on different build type in vscode.
I knew that adding `cmake.buildDirectory: "build/${buildType}"` in `setting.json` can fix this problem, but as the `setting.json` are changed easily when someone changes some configuration, it won't be convenient for Git to track it. So I want to move such settings into `cmake-kits.json` or `cmake-variants.json`, would it be possible?
 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Idk about the cmake-kits.json or cmake-variants.json.

I use CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE from inside relevant CMakeLists.txt or .cmake, and set target properties like RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR and ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIR and LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR.  use CMAKE_BINARY_DIR and add the path you want based on CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

One can also use the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to set the output directory for other non-target files the same way.

You should ensure to set a default value for CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE in case you like to run cmake from a command line as in 'cmake .' and nothing else, this way the cmake scripts won't have to assume which type you mean.